Graph traversal algorithm: when it is possible to move to the next node only after having visited it earlier with all incoming edges of the graph
There is a graph that consists of vertices (industrial installations) and edges flows of raw materials, intermediates and products between this nodes.
I need some kind of algorithm for "traversing" this graph from source nodes to consumer nodes.
The key requirement for the algorithm is that I can move from a certain node of the graph to the next one only if I have already visited this node before with all entering streams entering ( Edges of the graph)
For example. Suppose I have node A and B (sources) that are connected to node C (intermediate), and node C is connected to node D (consumer). The algorithm must first go from A to C, then from B to C, and only then from C to D. In other words, some calculations must be performed in node C and they can be done only after I have already visited it with all incoming flows earlier, then these calculations are used to evaluate the output C flow.
What mathematical algorithm will allow to do this?
And the second question is about the same part. Often in my graph, I see that some kind of flow has changed along the edge of a node that is in the middle or at the end of the graph. I need some kind of rule or algorithm that will determine the nodes of the graph that need to be recalculated.
For example, let node C be connected to node D explicitly (direct connection), while C is also connected to D implicitly (through node E). In turn, D has three incoming edges CD, CE->ED and some kind of node AD. So, when changing the characteristics of node C, the algorithm should go through the edges CD, and CED, but not AD, so as not to make unnecessary calculations and take the old value.

This might be topological traversal, I think

It's more like a level order tree reversal

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

A topological sort will solve the first problem.
That ordering is the order you should recalculate on a change, but only recalculate nodes that can be reached from what changed.
I'm going to sleep. I can clarify this tomorrow if it doesn't make sense.

Thank you all for the answers. I looked at the topological sorting and it seems that this is what is needed. As for the second question, then, indeed, after conducting a topological sorting by a node in the future, we can assume that the changes need to be recalculated in the sorted list of nodes from the node where these changes occurred. Although this does not completely avoid unnecessary recalculations, it will still reduce the dimension of the task somewhat.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
